# Function logging undefined and not the prime numbers

Tags: javascript

sorry for the simple and dumb question.

I have created a function that returns me a boolean if a number is prime or not

```
function isPrime(num) {
  var prime = true;

  for(i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      var prime = false
      break;
    }
  }

  return prime;
}
```

After the creation of this generic function, i wanted to call it from inside another one, where it would  check from 1 to the number chosen by the user, using `isPrime()` and log me only the prime numbers.

```
function give(userInput) {
  for(i = 1; i === userInput - 1; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i) === true){
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

But for a reason `give()`, is logging me back undefined.

I can't find out why and any help, is appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys. And sorry about any typos.

Comment: Change `for(i = 1; i === userInput - 1; i++)` to `for(i = 1; i < userInput ; i++)`

Comment: About `if (isPrime(i) === true)`, `if (isPrime(i))` is enough.

Comment: and stop redefining you variable in the for loop, change this`var prime = false` to just `prime = false` inside the for loop

Comment: Make sure `userInput` is a number.
`userInput=parseInt(userInput)` should do it.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey, thanks for the indentation re-formatting!
I was about to point out that it's a burden without it...

Comment: You don't need to check all the way to "num", either.

Comment: Put a semicolon (`;`) after `var prime = false` and get used to putting it after `if`s so you can use `else` without error/unpredicted behavior...

Comment: Consider adding `var` or `let` before `i` in the loop, so that it starts `for(var i = 0;`. That way `i` does not become a global variable.

Comment: @DaveNewton, you are correct!
Not only that - check until the square root,
We can store primes in an Array and check against them.

Comment: You guys are awesome. The amount of things i learned in 10 minutes is amazing.

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't declaring `i` at all. That means that `i` is created in *global scope*: both `isPrime()` and `give()` are referencing (and modifying the same `i`. That's one problem.

Another problem your loop in `give()`:

```
for(i = 1; i === userInput - 1; i++) { ... }
```

The *only* time the loop body will ever execute is if the user enters "2".

Amended your code should look something like this:

```
function isPrime( num ) {
  let prime = true ;

  for( let i = 2 ; i < num && prime ; i++ ) {
      prime = prime && ( num % i !== 0 );
  }

  return prime;
}

function give( userInput ) {
  for( let i = 1 ; i <= userInput ; i++ ) {
    if ( isPrime(i) ){
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Which, when run as `give( 100 )`, yields the expected:

```
1
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function give(userInput){

  // i is less or equal to the userInput
  for(let i = 0; i <= userInput; i++) {
    if(isPrime(i)) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: this indeed solved my issue. Thank you for the help.